# Nginx rewrite - .htacces to nginx

Tags: nginx

I want my apache .htaccess to work with nginx.

I've got this .htaccess file/code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will transform to something of this kind with nginx :

```
server {

    server www.domain.com;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the "index.php" in the url, I would do

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri @redirect;
        ...
    }

    location @redirect {
        return 301 $1/index.php;
    }
```